# antd 5.15.2 and dayjs 1.11.10 Datepickers do not change the start of the week to Monday

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, dayjs

after updating antd to version 5.15.2 everything worked well, since the dayjs version was 1.11.7 but there were errors with types, after updating dayjs to the latest version (1.11.10) in the datepicker the week always starts from Sunday and nothing helps

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import weekday from "dayjs/plugin/weekday";
import "dayjs/locale/en";
import updateLocale from "dayjs/plugin/updateLocale";
dayjs.locale("en");
dayjs.extend(updateLocale);
dayjs.extend(weekday);
dayjs.updateLocale("en", {
    weekStart: 1,
});
```

after changing the locale to different ones, nothing helped, if you roll back the dayjs version to 1.11.7 everything starts working and the days of the week in the datepicker are set as specified in the config